# Subscription testing possibility

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Can we test in app billing payment without using real credit card?Or is it mandatory to enter real credit card details to make test/real purchase?

I tried entering fake credit card detail for testing subscription with  account. It didn't work.

We are done with testing with static responses now wants to move ahead with testing

Is there any way for testing for subscription?

I want to test real subscription product..because want to get response of it to get date of ending also  any possibility  to restore if we uninstall app and again install app then can we restore that purchased subscription.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as SKU **android.test.purchased** and you will get an interface like this
[image]

Comment: thanks but...my question is not related with this...its different...just read carefully..

Comment: if you use, android.test.purchased sku, you don't need to enter any credit card information and this is the way to test if your code works or not.

Comment: i know that but i want to test real subscription product..because want to get response of it and any possibility  to restore if we uninstall app ans again install app then can we restore that purchased product.

Comment: in that case, you have to use real credit card, and you can refund it using the order management in the Play Store console.